# Reset model rotation when input stops

Tags: c#, 3d, matrix, xna

I have the model representing the player's ship gradually leaning when the player strafes. For instance, here's the code that leans the ship right:

In `Update()` of the Game class:

```
if (ship.rightTurnProgress < 1 && (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)))
{
    ship.rightTurnProgress += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 30;
}
```

In `Update()` of the Ship class:

```
if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
{
   Velocity += Vector3.Right * VelocityScale * 10.0f;
   RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) * 
     Matrix.CreateRotationY(0.4f * rightTurnProgress);
}
```

This is what I'm attempting to do to make it ease back out of the lean when it stops strafing:

In `Update()` of the Game class:

```
if (ship.rightTurnProgress > 0 && currentKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.D))
{
    ship.rightTurnProgress -= (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 30;
}
```

In `Update()` of the Ship class:

```
if (currentKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.D) && rightTurnProgress > 0)
{
    RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) *
      Matrix.CreateRotationY(-0.4f * rightTurnProgress);
}
```

Since easing into the lean works no problem, I thought easing out of the lean would be a simple matter of reversing the process. However, it tends to not go all the way back to the default position after a long strafe. If you tap the key, it snaps all the way back to the full lean of the -opposite- direction. This isn't what I expected at all. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you represent the rotation of you ship as a quaternion. That way you can use an interpolation function such as [slerp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198998.aspx). Simply have a second quaternion that represents you targeted lean angle and the ship will smoothly rotate until it achieves the targeted angle.

Here's a good tutorial on [quaternions](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Quaternions.php). If you want to avoid quaternions use MathHelper.Lerp to smoothly transition from the current value to the target.

```
if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
{
    ship.TurnProgress = MathHelper.Lerp(ship.TurnProgress, 1, somefloat * timeDelta);
}
else if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.a))
{
    ship.TurnProgress = MathHelper.Lerp(ship.TurnProgress, -1, somefloat * timeDelta);
}
else  (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
{
    ship.TurnProgress = MathHelper.Lerp(ship.TurnProgress, 0, somefloat * timeDelta);
}
```

Edit: Also there is a GameDev stack overflow so check it out if you have more questions.

Comment: I ended up changing the Update() in the Ship class a little for this (using one turn progress variable instead of two, and taking the rotation out of an if statement), but this worked out better than my original plan. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know how long the turn is or you have some kind of acceleration vector you will have to wait until the turn is stopped before returning the sprite angle to neutral, then what happens when the player turns left before the sprite has reached its neutral position?  I assume that when you turn right using RightTurnProgress you also have a LeftTurnProgress I suggest you combine them into one variable to keep it smooth and avoid the snapping effect you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an 'absolute' rotation matrix so you don't need to flip the sign to `-0.4f`. Why not just have a variable called `ship.lean` and calculate the rotation matrix every update. Then you just need logic to ease `ship.lean` between -1 (left lean) and 1 (right lean) or 0 for no lean.